# Backup client for Windows: open source, rsync and VSS

Tags: windows, backup, sync, rsync, vss

I'm looking for a sync/backup client for Windows with:

1. Open source license (BSD/GPL)
2. rsync deltas to a remote rsync server
3. VSS support

Command line interface is preferred to a GUI.

The less of everything else, the better.

Any ideas?

Comment: Tried [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)?

Comment: Is "VSS" *Visual SourceSafe* or *Shadow Copy*?

Comment: Hey! How about it now? Could it help me with this : http://superuser.com/q/931489/183293

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Duplicati meets all of your specifications http://code.google.com/p/duplicati/ - it supports VSS, uses deltas and has a commandline client in addition to the GUI.

Comment: Duplicati is great for this as long as you don't need to run the backup as a service. This is promised for version 2.

Comment: Duplicati doesn't use rsync.  It uses rdiff.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/duplicati/abqyUO3w9qU

Comment: Is this an option for what I need : http://superuser.com/q/931489/183293

Answer (score -1):

I have used [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/info.html)  before and was very pleased. My user base loved that they could restore their own files if they needed to recover data.

Comment: Problem with BackupPC is that using SMB to get the files does not allow snapshotting (VSS) of the filesystem and therefore does not allow backup of open files.